# how do i remove one pin from a map view that has multiple pins

Tags: swift, dictionary, annotations

I add multiple pins to a map view based on a database. How do I remove certain pins based on title.

This is how I added the pins
var pinsArray: [MKPointAnnotation] = []

```
   for i in (0..<dbarray_id.count)
        {

            let annotation2 = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: tmp_latitude, longitude: tmp_longitude)
            annotation2.title = dbarray_email[i]
            annotation2.subtitle = dbarray_geogroup[i]
            pinsArray.append(annotation2)
            map.addAnnotation(annotation2)
        }
```

Later i want to certain pins. I tried

```
    for annotation_point in map.annotations
    {
        if annotation_point.title  ==  "POA"
        {
            map.removeAnnotation(annotation_point)
        }
    }
```

But get error:  binary operator == cannot be applied to operands of type String?? and Sting

When I add a pin annotation I copy it to the array pinsArray.

So basically how do I remove a certain pin base on a criteria.

Thanks

Comment: It's generally recommended to use camel case variable names in Swift, as stated in the official design guideline: https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if let title = annotation_point.title, title  == "POA" {
    // Rest of the code goes here...
}
```

Comment: By the way can you update an "existing" pin location?

Comment: @alover Yes you can, but you will need to cast your `annotation_point` to `MKPointAnnotation`. Try this: `if let pointAnnotation = annotation_point as? MKPointAnnotation { /* change point here */}`